# How to launch view controller from alarm notification action in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

In my app i am using alarm functionality. It working fine. When i click the right button it launches my app. But i want to launch View Controller which is not an rootViewController. I am tried in searching in Google and SO but i couldn't get any idea or example.

I am looking for any example to achieve this.?

Thanks for your help guys.

**EDIT**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:alarmViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;


// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);

    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [window rootViewController];
    [rootViewController presentModalViewController:receipeViewController animated:YES];         
}


// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
// Handle the notificaton when the app is running
NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);   
//Called here as well
window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [window rootViewController];
    [rootViewController presentModalViewController:receipeViewController animated:YES];   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally Here's how I did it.

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
//save the root view controller
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*) self.window.rootViewController;
rootController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Somewhere else in the app delegate:

```
[rootController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"destinationSegue" sender:self];
```

Then, in the storyboard, create a segue from the view that gets assigned to "rootController" to the desired optional view, and give that new segue the id destinationSegue. It takes some debugging to make sure the rootController variable gets assigned to the correct view.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create a segue.You only need to assign an id in the storyboard for the ViewController.

```
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    LensOverviewViewController *editLensViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lensOverView"];
    UINavigationController *yourViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editLensViewController];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:yourViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Normally [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible]; does not reside in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function but it needs to be called explicity to make the rootviewcontroller visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIViewcontroller *rootViewController = [window rootViewController];
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:alarmViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer George.. i know this question is simple where do i want to add this code.. i tried adding in `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {[self presentModalViewController:alarmViewController animated:YES];}` it says `Instance method '-presentModalViewController:animated:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: Try it in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: I edited my question please have a look at that.. i know some where i am doing wrong thanks

Comment: When you create the receipe view controller?

Comment: oh..i am not creating the recipe view controller any where.. do i want to create like this `receipeViewController = [[RecipeDetailsViewController alloc]init];` before calling

Comment: some view appears and gone to black screen George.. what will be the issue +1 for your support

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15345/discussion-between-vinoth-and-george-sachin)

Answer (score 0):

When your application is launched, look for the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey on the launchOptions dictionary on the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This will let you know if your application is being launched because of a local notification (the one you use for the alarm).

You can also do something similar on:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Once you determine that you actually received a notification, just find the root view controller from the window and present the view controller you want to present modally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to call the view controller in `didReceiveLocalNotification` method.. Much appreciated

Comment: i edited my question with my code please have a look at it.. thanks for your suppor

Comment: Just initialize the view controller you want to present, or get it from where it is if it is already initialized.

Comment: `receipeViewController = [[RecipeDetailsViewController alloc]init];
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [window rootViewController];
    [rootViewController presentModalViewController:receipeViewController animated:YES];` This is my code on didReceiveLocalNotification but not working is that right

Comment: something happens and gone to black screen J2theC +1 for your support

Comment: check if that is the correct initializer for your view controller. usually it's initWithNibName:bundle: .

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I am using storyboard how to get the initwithNibName.. Sorry i am very new.. i am really worried.. if you could please add some example for code for initialization

Comment: Check the documentation for UIStoryboard. The way to initialize the view controller is instantiateInitialViewController.